Mahalanobis whitening - ZCA whitening with matrix of two rows, n columns
Is there a minimum matrix size for Mahalanobis whitening transformations?
I have recently been searching a package for Rstudio that allows ZCA whitening (Mahalanobis) for matrices of 2 rows, but I seem not to find any. I was told by that this might not even be possible.
Thanks.

Let $X$ be the $p\times n$ matrix of the data with $n$ denoting the number of (independent) observations and $p$ the number of outcomes of interest. The (empirical) Mahalanobis whitening of $X$ is given by $$Y := \sqrt{n-1}(XCX^\top)^{-\frac 12}(XC),$$ where $C := I_n - \frac 1n1_n^{~}1_n^\top$ is the centering matrix ($I_n$ is the $n$ dimensional identity matrix and $1_n$ is a (column) vector consisting of $n$ ones).
As you can see the Mahalanobis whitening involves computing the inverse of $XCX$. If $n<p$, we have that $\operatorname{rank}(XCX^\top) = n - 1$, that is, $XCX^\top$ is not surjective, and $XCX^\top$ does not exist. So you need $n>p$ to be able to apply the (empirical) Mahalanobis whitening. From a theoretical point of view, it would be possible to replace the matrix square root of $(XCX^\top)^{-1}$ by the matrix square root of $(XCX^\top)^+$, where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix $A$. However, I don't know if standard packages provide this computation.
